# Encode Webcam input in browser

Tags: flash, web-applications, activex

Hello，I need to get the webcam input in my web app through web browser, encode it to h264 and stream it to our server.
The flash client app works fine before the encoding problems involved.
It seems that I could not access the video data from the camera object in flash actionscripts. could I?
If not, Then I will try to write some browser plugin to do the quest. I will try activeX in IE but I'm new to it, are there some tutorials or sample code for the webcam input process in activeX?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with FMS or via some custom rig on FFPMEG/MENCODER i should think. You want to capture the data from the webcam stream and encode to h624 on the fly so you'd need some kind of server-side video processing solution.